# SQL Server: Group by not yielding correct order of results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to write a query where the results would be grouped by month&year and 'Grade'. For example the table data is:

```
DECLARE @Scores TABLE (
    [SubmissionDate] DATETIME,
    [Score] INT,
    [Grade] VARCHAR(7)
)
INSERT INTO @Scores VALUES
('2018-08-01', 60, 'AVERAGE'),
('2018-08-01', 50, 'POOR'),
('2018-09-01', 68, 'AVERAGE'),
('2018-09-01', 66, 'AVERAGE'),
('2018-07-01', 64, 'AVERAGE'),
('2018-07-01', 56, 'POOR'),
('2018-08-01', 62, 'AVERAGE'),
('2018-08-01', 80, 'GOOD'),
('2018-09-01', 52, 'POOR'),
('2018-09-01', 54, 'POOR'),
('2018-07-01', 58, 'POOR'),
('2018-08-01', 50, 'POOR'),
('2018-09-01', 82, 'GOOD'),
('2018-09-01', 86, 'GOOD'),
('2018-07-01', 62, 'AVERAGE'),
('2018-07-01', 84, 'GOOD'),
('2018-07-01', 82, 'GOOD'),
('2018-08-01', 88, 'GOOD')
```

What I need is average of score for each month for each grade. I am able to get the average correct. For me, what is not working is the order of months. The results are being shown ordered alphabetically(Aug is shown before July and then Sep) The correct order should be -> Jul, Aug, Sep

Here is the query I have written:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, [SubmissionDate])),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YY, [SubmissionDate]) AS [Range]
       ,[Score]
       ,[Grade]
    FROM @Scores
)
SELECT [Range], AVG([Score]) AS [AverageScore], [Grade]
FROM CTE GROUP BY [Range], [Grade]
```

Here is the output:

```
Range       AverageScore    Grade
AUG-2018    61              AVERAGE
JUL-2018    63              AVERAGE
SEP-2018    67              AVERAGE
AUG-2018    84              GOOD
JUL-2018    83              GOOD
SEP-2018    84              GOOD
AUG-2018    50              POOR
JUL-2018    57              POOR
SEP-2018    53              POOR
```

I need the correct order of first column.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is not `ORDER BY`. If you fail to include an `ORDER BY` clause in any query, you're giving the server free rein to return the rows in whatever order is most convenient for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting the year first, followed by the month name.  Then, `ORDER BY` using that value converted to a `datetime` via `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        DATENAME(YY, [SubmissionDate]) + '-' +
            LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, [SubmissionDate])), 3) AS [Range],
        [Score],
        [Grade]
    FROM @Scores
)

SELECT
    [Range],
    AVG([Score]) AS [AverageScore],
[Grade]
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    [Range],
    [Grade]
ORDER BY
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, [Range]);
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: If you wanted to also add another order level, either before or after the date, you may do so, and it should not affect the ordering logic used above.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, [SubmissionDate])),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YY, [SubmissionDate]) AS [Range], [SubmissionDate]
,[Score]
,[Grade]
FROM @Scores
)
SELECT [Range], AVG([Score]) AS [AverageScore], [Grade]
FROM CTE GROUP BY [Range], [Grade],[SubmissionDate]
order by [SubmissionDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional column for sorting.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, [SubmissionDate])),3) + '-' + DATENAME(YY, [SubmissionDate]) AS [Range]
        ,[Score]
        ,[Grade]
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), [SubmissionDate], 112) AS [RangeOrder] -- ISO: 112 = yyyymmdd
    FROM @Scores
)
SELECT 
    [Range], 
    AVG([Score]) AS [AverageScore], 
    [Grade]
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY [Range], [Grade], [RangeOrder]
ORDER BY [RangeOrder]
```

Result:

```
Range                              AverageScore Grade
---------------------------------- ------------ -------
JUL-2018                           63           AVERAGE
JUL-2018                           83           GOOD
JUL-2018                           57           POOR
AUG-2018                           61           AVERAGE
AUG-2018                           84           GOOD
AUG-2018                           50           POOR
SEP-2018                           67           AVERAGE
SEP-2018                           84           GOOD
SEP-2018                           53           POOR
```